# Why is the queue the best approach for finding the number of recent calls? [Leetcode problem]

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-3.6

I just worked on the 'Number of Recent Calls' problem on Leetcode. I read it wanted me to return the number of pings but had no idea on how to go about it.

Description is here:

> Write a class RecentCounter to count recent requests.
>
> It has only one method: ping(int t), where t represents some time in milliseconds.
>
> Return the number of pings that have been made from 3000 milliseconds ago until now.
>
> Any ping with time in [t - 3000, t] will count, including the current ping.
>
> It is guaranteed that every call to ping uses a strictly larger value of t than before.

I learned that you immedietely have to know that you need to use a queue. I had no idea and just wanted to know if anyone could explain a why you need to use a queue for this problem. Here is one solution.

```
import collections

class recentCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = collections.deque()

    def ping(self, t: int):
        self.p.append(t)
        while self.p[0] < t - 3000:
            self.p.popleft()
        return len(self.p)
```

Comment: You don't *have* to uses a `deque`, but a `deque` has a constant time `popleft` operation, which is more efficient than an equivalent `my_list.pop(0)` which would be linear time on a `list` object

Answer (score 0):

A queue is just a subclass of array, where new values are `append`ed to the bottom and old values are `popleft`ed from the top.

You don't absolutely need this to solve your problem; you could `append` every new value to the array with a timestamp, and then iterate over the array to return only values from the last three seconds.  However, a queue is much more elegant.  This solution keeps keeps your array only as long as it has to be, and then requires no extra work to yield the desired result.

Comment: A queue is not a subclass of `array` (assuming you mean either `array.array` or `list`, but it is a subclass of neither). Furthermore, it isn't simply more elegant, it is more efficient than a list here, because `.popleft` is constant time with a `deque` object vs linear time with the equivalent operation on a `list` object

Comment: You're right, subclass was imprecise; I meant the concept of a queue, and "sub-type" would be better.  Important to point out the time saving as well!

Comment: Thanks everyone. So the takeaway is that it is more optimal but you don't always have to use a queue?

Comment: There are solutions that don't require a queue, but for this problem, you absolutely should use one.